Add controller support to .NET 8 Blazor Wasm
What do I need to do to get controllers added to a .NET 8 Blazor Wasm app? The template now creates the counter and weather, hardcoded in the Razor page which is no use at all.
The template used to add controllers. How do I get this functionality back?
I have tried to set it up by adding builder.Services.AddHttpClient(), UseControllers() etc. but I just get a 404 when trying to call the controller endpoint.
This is my server project program.cs:
using RWeb.Client.Pages;
using RWeb.Components;
using RWeb.Controllers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); // Add this line

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting(); // Add this line
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.UseAuthorization(); // Add this line

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(RecoWeb.Client._Imports).Assembly);
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

And this is the program.cs for the client project:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
await builder.Build().RunAsync();

Just to be clear, this is a WASM Hosted app with a client and server project.

You cannot add controllers to a Blazor WASM project.  You have to create a separate web service project and put your controllers and other service layer code there.

@TGnat - there are 2 program.cs here.

"but I just get a 404" - show the controller, with all routing attributes. And a call from the client.

May I know whether you are working on a blazor web assembly project or a blaor web app interactive auto render mode application? Because there won't be 2 Program.cs inside a standalone WASM app. But interactive auto app should have app.MapRazorComponents<App>()     .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()     .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()     .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(ProjectName.Client._Imports).Assembly); which is different from yours. So that it looks like you are working on a blazor WASM but having asp.net core hosted app. Could you pls help confirm it?

In my humble opinion, blazor WASM standalone application is the same as Angular/React which is SPA, so the question get controllers added to a .NET 8 Blazor Wasm app is similar to get controllers added to an React app which might be uncommon. You also mentioned The template used to add controllers. How do I get this functionality back? so that I'm afraid that you are trying to get the asp.net core hosted blazor WASM app back but it's removed indeed. You can create a seperate .net core API project to server the blazor WASM app.

This is not a standalone app. It is a WASM hosted app. So there is a client and server project. The template used to hook up the server controllers etc but no longer does for some stupid reason.

Damn it! It was so obvious when I look at it now. Intellisense (copilot) added completed the api call with "api/testcontroller" and I had not noticed. I removed the controller to leave "api/test" and it works...

Hmmm, glad to see the app running well now. May I know whether you are working on a .Net8 blazor project which is upgraded from .Net 7/6 and that's why you have hosted service project?

Blazor in .Net 8 removed the Blazor Server template and the “ASP.NET Core hosted” option from the Blazor WebAssembly template. We can see the description in this blog. As an alternative option, we have blazor web app now.
In my humble opinion, you are now trying to get Blazor web assembly + asp.net core hosted in .Net 8. So that I think there're 2 option as an replacement now. One is that we use blazor web assembly standalone application, then we create another web api project in the same solution to serve it. Just need to add CORS policy in the web api project.

Another option is using blazor web app, in order to continue to get the benefit from web assembly, you can choose the render mode as Interactive Auto. Then you can expose Controller in the service project and send Http request from the Client project to get the data you need.
